# Reassigning variable in Python

Tags: python, variable-assignment

In Python, I have an expensive function `a(x)` which is currently evaluated multiple times within another function. At the start of that function, I want to evaluate `a(x)` once, and reassign the variable name `a` locally to that value. But I keep getting an Unbound Local Error.

As a MWE:

```
def a(x):
    return x+1

def main(x):
    a = a(x)
    return a**2

main(3)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
#Input In [62], in <cell line: 8>()
#      5     a = a(x)
#      6     return a**2
#----> 8 main(3)
#
#Input In [62], in main(x)
#      4 def main(x):
#----> 5     a = a(x)
#      6     return a**2

#UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Obviously, a workaround is to use a line like `b = a(x)` instead.

But why is this happening? And how can I reassign the variable name a?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just name it `b`.

Comment: Obviously, but I don't understand why the error arises. Hence, my question.

Comment: The function definition `a` is essentially a `global` name in the module. To assign to it you need to declare it `global` within the scope of the function (in this case `main`).

Comment: However, this won't mean you can use the variable instead of the function as you use the function call syntax `a()`. Why not call `a()` and then pass the result to the function (`main` in this case)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that I cannot define a local variable `a`, because a global variable `a` is already defined. In order to change the variable definition of `a`, I need to change it globally, and cannot change it locally.

Comment: I do not understand your other suggestion. Calling `a(x)` is something I do already in the main function. When I try to assign it to a local variable `a`, that's where issues arise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247413/discussion-between-david-and-peter-wood).

Comment: I think that should help: [`UnboundLocalError` on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use/370363#370363)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because in this line:

```
    a = a(x)
```

you are redefining `a` to be a local variable.  This occurs for *all* uses for `a` within that scope, *including the right hand side of the expression*.  `a` doesn't start off as a global and then become a local at some point during the function's execution at runtime; if there is an assignment to `a` *anywhere* in the function, then `a` is now a local *everywhere* in that function.

That means that when that line is actually executed, it's attempting to call the local variable `a` before anything has been assigned to it.

Here's a simpler demonstration of the same effect, where we aren't changing the type of `a`, and we aren't referencing it on the same line where we're assigning to it:

```
>>> a = 42
>>> def foo():
...     print(a)  # should be 42, right?
...     if False:
...         a = 42  # should be a no-op, right?
...
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

In this case, the rebinding of `a` happens *after* it's used, *and* it happens in a block that will never even actually be executed when the function is *called* -- but it doesn't matter, because at the time the function is *defined*, the existence of that assignment makes `a` a local variable.

You can actually see this by inspecting `foo` itself, without calling it:

```
>>> foo.__code__.co_varnames
('a',)
```

Compare with an implementation that doesn't make `a` into a local:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print(a)
...
>>> foo()
42
>>> foo.__code__.co_varnames
()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you have already named 'a' as a function that you can't assign as a variable again instead of

```py
a = a(x)
```

you can name it some other variable like 'b' like this

```py
def main(x):
    b = a(x)
    return b**2
```

Comment: Yes, but *why* can I not redefine `a` locally?

Comment: This example might be useful: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value.  Note, the problem in the non-working code example given there isn't per se that `x` is reassigned as local.  It's that the global `x` then can't be used *anywhere in the function, even before the reassigment of x*, so the print statement fails.

Comment: because Python recognizes it as a function that's why

Comment: @Vatsal but `def main(x): a = 42; return a * x` would be ok.  The `main` function is allowed to redefine `a` as local, but if it does that then it can't *also* use the global `a`, as it does in `a = a(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `a` as global variable:

```
def a(x):
    return x+1

def main(x):
    global a  # <<<<<<<< only this line need to be added.
    a = a(x)  # Now a is first called (right side) and then reassigned
    return a**2

print(main(3))
```

Now it works!

Output:

```
16
```

If you check what is `a` now:

```
print(a)
```

Output:

```
4
```

So global `a` has changed. Its no more a function and it cannot be called now:

```
print(a(3))
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Although `print(main(3) + main(4))` might cause a surprise!

Comment: Yes, I have added reason for this in the answer above.